# Jquery .index() not working though WAMP

Tags: javascript, jquery, wamp, mamp

I am having a very strange issue with .index(). I have been building something locally and everything is working fine. As soon as i put the code on WAMP/MAMP local hosting the .index() counting stops working properly.

> ```
> var prodCont = $(".disaCats");
>
> prodCont.each(function(){
> //Checking too see how Many products the category has
> var tempIndex = $(this).children(".cardContainer").index();
>
> //If the there are more than 6 products show the dropdownArrow
> if(tempIndex > 5){
>       $(this).siblings(".disaHeading").children(".showMoreArrow").show();
> });//end index calculation
> ```

I used an alert to return the tempIndex and it returns 0 for each item.

I have tried using .index(this) and just .children() without the class selector but it does the same thing. Im starting to think this is an issue with WAMP/MAMP.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: This script runs fine through localhost/ on WAMP/MAMP, but as soon as i try and share it using my ip 521.xxx.xxx/ this is when the index counting stops working properly.

Comment: WAMP can't impact how javascript executes, javascript is client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what `index()` does. The [documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

You do not want index! You want to know the number of children elements. To get that, you want to use `.length`

```
var tempIndex = $(this).children(".cardContainer").length;
```

Comment: why does it return 6 when im running it locally?

Comment: I do not know, maybe you have different cached jQuery versions? All I know is if you want the number of children it should be length. index() is for something totally different.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `index()` with `length` to get the number of elements in the collection :

```
//Checking too see how Many products the category has
var tempIndex = $(this).children(".cardContainer").length;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Seems to be working okay. Im still confused why I have never run into this issue before and why it was working locally.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a logic issue right here, `index` gives you the index of the element within the collection, but it's collection is the list of children, so the index of the first child of that collection is always going to be `0`.  If you use `index` on a collection then the default behavior is to perform the call on the first element, which is why you always get `0`.  If you actually just want to total number of children then I would recommend using `length` instead of `index`.